# How to solve this word problem, correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if you can help me with this algebra word problem that I am confused.

> Estimate the amount of plastic trim used around the floor mat shown below. 
>   (Let $a = 44, b = 56, c = 8$, and $d = 12$). Just tell me what am I suppose to do.

[image]

Comment: They want you to find the perimeter of the figure. Add up all the side lengths.

Comment: yes, I added up and its 120 . is that correct

Comment: It's very unkind to those who aided you by giving you an answer for you to delete your question immediately after someone posts an answer. It also makes it appear like you are hiding your question. I've undeleted this question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your supposed to determine the perimeter. So you would add up each section or the perimeter to get a linear length of needed boarder.

So going around from the top:
a + (b-d) + c + d + c + a + c + d + c + (b-d)

this simplifies to:
2*a + 2*b + 4*c = 2*44 + 2*56 + 4*8 = 232

Comment: yes, I added up and its `120` . is that correct?